# Django admin_order_field on custom field that is formatted/decrypted

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a database with some fields that are encrypted. In the admin page i created a custom function to decrypt field value(full_name column) and show on the listing page:

```
#admin.py
list_display = ('get_full_name',)

def get_full_name(self, obj):
        if obj.full_name is not None:
            return decrypt_string(obj.full_name)
        else:
            return None
    get_full_name.short_description = 'User full name'
    get_full_name.admin_order_field = 'full_name'
```

I though it would ordering over the decrypted string but it order by the encrypted values instead.

[image]

How can i have an order by decrypted value on the admin listing page ?

Comment: To clarify. Are you wanting the default ordering (when you open the page) to be by your decrypted full name, or are you wanting the option to sort by decrypted full name (by clicking the column). If the later, I think this is not possible (although I may be wrong there). If the former then this is possible.

Comment: Also, if the decrypted value is available for anyone who has access to django-admin, there's no reason why you can't make it available to anyone who has access to the database. Just don't expose the decrypted value on any public facing APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Apply orderby on the decrypted data.

data = data.order_by('decrypted_data') // place the decrypted data in the order_by

Comment: where should i put this in ? get_queryset() ? that would defeat the purpose of dynamic sort. I don't think you can use it as simple as `order_by('decrypted_data')`, because the decrypt data is not a field on the table

Comment: Then on that data apply sort, as the result is a list. list.sort()